# First application android, relationship between activity and service

Tags: android

I have trouble in my first application, I would like to know how I can interact with a `Service` from my `Activity`. The app uses the accelerometer, not just measure a certain value should take a picture and call the activity to save it.

Comment: You should read a lot about services and understand them before continuing. Start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

Comment: Not an appropriate stackoverflow question. You don't have a technical issue, you just have not read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should understand more about Activity And Service

In simple words to make you understand

**Activity**
Its like you performing some action, like talking, walking, something where User will see and operate.

**Service**
Its like your breathing system, your blood circulation system you don't make sure your blood is circulate at an interval. It just happens.

Yes, in programming Android you have the ability to start a Service when you desire, Stop a Service.
But you can't get the value back from the service like you can get in `function()` .

I hope I have given some idea from real world to make you understand.

Yes, in your case you could keep your service of accelerometer running. Once it reaches a particular value you can make sure that your `Service` takes the picture for you in the `background`.

Thats something you can do. I hope I have given you a satisfactory explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to interact with a web service then
Use HttpClient,HttpGet , HttpPost objects.

Check this link for details.
http://kasperholtze.com/android/android-getting-data-from-a-webservice/

Answer (score -1):

Fire an Intent from Activity Like below :

Intent intent=new Intent(this,Service.class);

startService(intent);